# Does JQuery Toggle() function only supports div to hide?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, toggle, tablerow

I'm trying to set up a toggle function to show more content IN A TABLE.

So here it is, I can't do much things with my < tr >, I don't know if its because I missed something or because toggle() only works with < div > ?

Here is what I did :

The script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready (a little sooner that page load)
  $('.hidden').hide();

 // slides down, up, and toggle the slickbox on click    

  $('.more-info').click(function() {
    $('.hidden').slideToggle(1000);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

The button :

```
<div style="float:right;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more-info">Show more</a>
</div>
```

The table (the tr to Toggle):

```
<tr class="hidden">
    <td>
        <img id="tableImage" src="<?php echo base_url($product['image_url'])?>" alt="product" width="121"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product['title'] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $options = array(
                         '0'  => '0',
                         '1'  => '1',
                         '2'  => '2',
                         '3'  => '3',
                         '4'  => '4',
                         '5'  => '5',
                         '6'  => '6',
                         '7'  => '7',
            );

            if($product['quantity']==0){
               $value[$product['title']] = set_value('quantity'.$product['title']);
            }else{
               $value[$product['title']] = $product['quantity'];
            }

            $data0 = 'class="quantSelect" value="'.$value[$product['title']].'" id="quant'.$product['title'].'"';
            echo    form_dropdown('quantity'.$product['title'], $options, $value[$product['title']],$data0);
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $product['price'] ?>
    </td>
    <td id="<?php echo 'price'.$product['title']?>">$<?php echo $total[$product['title']] ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you mind making a jsFiddle?

Comment: Where `more-info` is placed ?

Comment: Can you show me your code ? Let's try to organize it first.

Comment: @Inkbug: I don't know what is a jsFiddle sorry, I'm not a jquery expert, can you tell me more plz ?

Comment: @Ricardo Lohmann: more info is the button, the second code. I tried to separate my script from my button and my table, the page is actually pretty long so I just put the necessary parts.

Comment: The thing is that my tr doesn't even hide ..

Comment: @MilesM. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle()` is definitely not limited just to div elements, indeed it appears to work fine with tr elements: http://jsfiddle.net/sdWVU/ - including if you specify a duration: http://jsfiddle.net/sdWVU/1/

However, your code doesn't actually use `.toggle()`, it uses `.slideToggle()`. That doesn't "work" with a tr element in the sense that it does hide and show the element but it doesn't slide it: http://jsfiddle.net/sdWVU/2/ The lack of slide effect is a limitation of how tables work.

If you want to make the row hide and show with animation I suggest `.toggle('slow')`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried replacing .slideToggle() by toggle() but it doesn't work neither, my tr don't even hide ..

Comment: I've been making the function work ! thanks, the pb was coming from another script that was influencing this one, I don't know why. They both crash together but if I delete the other one, it works with toggle. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about `toggleClass`?

```
$('.more-info').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    return false;
});

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Other thing, **why don't you separate PHP from HTML**?

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kb2yJ/1/) can help you.

Comment: okay I'm trying toggleClass, I need to read the doc about that class. You think my code contains too much php ? this is the view, with, for me, the strict necessary, how can I put less php ?

Comment: @MilesM. Move `options` and `ifs` out of `tr`.